# Realtime Firebase Database foreground childListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project there is a SOS button which pushes into Realtime Firebase Database sender-user email, receiver-user email and time. It looks like this:

[image: firebase database]

I have to make foreground listener, which will scan data from realtime database all the time (even when the app is terminated), and compare emailTo value with my (current user's) email and send notification if data matches.

---

I tried to make the service, but it dies in 10 seconds, idk how it works, can you help me with anything (send guide or smth).

In three words: I need service which scans realtime databse all the time and sends notificaton if data mathces.

Comment: Why aren't you using [Cloud Function for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)?

Comment: I don't know...( How much time it will take to change from Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore? Is my question task even possible?

Comment: For sure it is. Cloud Function for Firebase works really well with Firestore, as well with the Realtime Database.

Comment: Can you give me guide or smth?

Comment: @AlexMamo How can I send sos-button click from one user to another(just my question), is there any example?

Comment: @AlexMamo to use cloud functions with realtime database i need to write something in JS? Can you give me any guide?

Comment: Can I make it without cloud services? Or its unreal?

Comment: You can do you as well from the client using a service. Have you tried something that way?

Comment: @AlexMamo well, this app is my it school project, and soon I will have to submit it, I think I will send SOSmessage just by SMS. I don't have much time for Cloud Services and other. Thank you for all your help.